# Como acessar as propriedades de uma classe que está dentro de outra classe?

Tags: c#, wpf

Tenho esse controle customizado:

```
public class CustomButton : Button
{
     public Test Test { get; set; }
}
```

E essa classe:

```
public class Teste
{
     public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Eu quero alterar essa propriedade `MyProperty`, fazer isso no C# é muito fácil, porém tenho que fazer isso no XAML e não funciona. O que estou usando até agora é isso:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <cc:Teste x:Key="Exemplo" MyProperty="Exemplo"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<cc:CustomButton Test="{StaticResource Exemplo}"/>
```

Porém recebo aquele erro muito comum de `NullReferenceException`. Como posso acessar essa propriedade `MyProperty` e alterar o valor dela pelo XAML?

Comment: O erro no C#, e não no XAML, você precisa inicializar o objeto antes de acessá-lo. Você manipula dados no C#, XMAL não é uma linguagem de programação.

Comment: @Maniero Eu fiz o que você falou, instanciei a classe Test, porém acontece outro problema, no exemplo que deixei a cima, deixo a propriedade MyProperty com o valor "Exemplo", fiz alguns testes aqui e uma hora o valor de MyProperty é simplesmente nada e outra hora é o texto de Exemplo, nunca fica somente Exemplo.

Comment: É como se eu tivesse duas instancias de Test, uma hora chama a que está com o texto, outra hora chama a que está sem texto.